# Retrieving YAML from a text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

The serialize method allows an object like a hash to be stored in the database as a YAML string.  However, I recently found myself wanting to have a text field to allow a user to input their own string and have the controller create a hash off of that string.

```
<%= f.text_field :yaml, :value => '--- \nlast_name: Smith\nfirst_name: Joe\n' %>
```

Yes, I want single quotes: I want to preserve the \n in the display.  But the problem is that, as a result, the resultant string object gets escaped:

```
--- \\nlast_name: Smith\\nfirst_name: Joe\\n
```

I run the string through two regexes:  The first replaces the double backslash with a single backslash.  Then next converts \n (two characters) into \n (special single character).

So in my controller:

```
yhash = YAML.load(params[:form][:yaml].gsub(/\\\\/, "\\").gsub(/\\n/, "\n"))
```

This now works, but seems awfully convoluted.  Is there a more elegant way for a user to submit yaml?

Comment: Can you rephrase that more concisely?

Comment: Could you explain why you would like to do this?  Rails escapes this text to avoid security exploits.  Making a data structure out of user entered serial code and trusting that could be dangerous. Seems like any use case for this would better be done another way.

Comment: +1 I agree. There's a real "exploit" stink there.

Comment: The resultant structure is just used to define parsing instructions, which I wanted to be able to "test" on the fly using a form.  I suppose I could have created a regex input form as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the users to be able to write `\n` to mark the newlines in the yaml they are entering? Because in that case the way you are doing it now with regexps is very straightforward.

The escape sequence `\n` is a feature of Ruby strings. If you want to implement it in your web form yaml interface too, a regexp is a valid way to do that.

Are you sure you have to do the double-slash replacement? I think it should only show up as double-slash if you do `.inspect`.